# Can a citrus tree produce fruit after a freeze?

Tags: trees, citrus

My citrus tree is in a large pot on the patio where it gets lots of sunlight.  Two summers ago, it was filled with blooms, but they all fell off.  We had a hard freeze that winter and it looked dead.  However, it came back to life, but grew three sprouts from the original graft.  Will it produce?

Comment: You may want to have a look at this post, too — **[Will my lime tree recover from cold shock?](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/1313/85)**

Answer (score 2):

If the new growth is above the graft line, then there's no reason that the plant wouldn't continue to grow and produce fruit as long as you take care of it properly: watering, feeding, pruning and so on.  It might take a couple of years before it has recovered enough to produce fruit.

If the new growth is below the graft line, it will probably produce, same as above, but it's almost certain that the rootstock will be a different variety of citrus, so the type of fruit you get won't be the same type of fruit that the tree originally produced.